# is there any efficient way to get a random value from a dinamically updated java ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java

if I have a ConcurrentHashMap that is always being updated (adding more or taking entries.. sometimes could be empty)...

is there any efficient way in constant time that, I could randomly get a value from it?

Comment: Can't you just take a random element from map.entrySet()?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a way to get a random-access view of the keys or entries without somewhere in the guts of it making an O(n) copy. The copy might be extremely fast though; don't optimise until you know it's a problem.

The only alternative I can think of is to keep a list of entries in parallel with your map. Any time you add to the map, also add to the list. Any time you remove from one, remove from the other. You could wrap this in your own implementation of `Map`:

```
   public class RandomAccessConcurrentHashMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V> {

        private List<K> backingList = new ArrayList();
        private Map<K,V> backingMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        public V put(K key, V value) {
            backingList.add(value);
            return backingMap.put(key,value);
        }

        ...
   }
```

(In principle -- you would need to do some thinking about thread-safety, and could probably find a more efficient store than `ArrayList`)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two step :

1 - Clon the values to an array at any time

2 - Get a random value from array through generating random index

```
Random generator = new Random();
Object[] values = concurrentHashMap.values().toArray();
Object randomValue = values[generator.nextInt(values.length)];
```

Comment: it's not constant time though

Comment: volatile int mapSize = concurrentHashMap.values.size(); to get the constant size of the map.

Comment: when doing .toArray, you copy all elements in linear time. so it becomes a bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

Does the map's size change? If it doesn't then the best approach I can think of of is to do:

```
map.values().get(random);
```

You could also do this with the keyset:

```
map.get(map.keyset().get(random));
```

Note that reader threads don't block writer threads, but writers can in rare cases block readers. This means that an unlucky write (or for that matter a garbage collection) can block the read operation and slow down execution.

If you were willing to accept a slightly less random approach you could potentially create an algorithm that avoids reading from areas where writes are occuring in order to prevent the speed loss due to locking.

When calling the constructor of the ConcurrentHashMap make sure you specify the concurrency level as the default value optimises  a the  internal  sharding for 16 writers, which is probably too much.